# Excel: Multiple column lookup and count

Tags: excel, vlookup, lookup

I'm sorry but I don't know how to google this. I have a table that looks like this:

```html
response|item|            categoryA| categoryB
----------------------------------------------
Yes     item1             item1       item2
No      item2             item3       item4
No      item3
yes     item4
No      item1 
Yes     item2
```

Each item belongs to one of two categories: A or B. The items are also listed in the 'item' column. Each item appears in the Item column multiple times, but only in the Category lookup columns once. Each instance of an item comes with a response, yes or no. **I need a count of how often the category A and B items receive a 'Yes' response, respectively.**

For instance: the table above would yield

Category A: 1 Category B: 2

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNTIFS where the criteria are the list of items in the category A or category B list, then SUMPRODUCT to combine the results for each item.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$3:$A$8,"Yes",$B$3:$B$8,D3:D4))
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, so simple! I was convinced I had to use vlookup!